# Mixing overlapping and disjoint specialization in E-R model

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I need to model the following specialization problem:

**There are three types of buildings: residential, commercial, and industrial. Some buildings can be mixed (residential and commercial).**

My problem with this is that I can't find an obvious way to model the fact that residential and commercial buildings can overlap, industrial ones can't (if a building is industrial, it can't be residential nor commercial, and obviously it can't be mixed either).

[If I ignore the "mixed" part, it's pretty easy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ8RY.png) But this way there can be no mixed buildings.

My attempts at implementing a "mixed" specialization have all failed. How can I model a specialization that is overlaps some children, but the overlapping children are disjoint from the rest?

I'm using the E-R model taught in Database Management Systems by Raghu Ramakrishnan.

Comment: How have your attempts failed?

Comment: I think an argument can be made for where you would normally enforce this logic, as it sounds like business logic which would generally not be done on a database level, however you could enforce this with a constraint. I am not aware of mapping conditional constraints like these on ERDs though. Maybe double check your question?

Comment: Well, I checked with my lecturer and he did say this could only be enforced with a constraint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this can only be enforced with a constraint. Thanks to everyone who gave some thought to this.